# Multiple connected Radio input forms on single page

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to implement multiple radio forms on a single page that communicate with each other.

So when you select a radio value in form A at the top of the page. It should display the same choice at the bottom on the page in form B. And vice versa.

How do i make this work?

i tried the following code:

```
const $selected = $('.course-date input:checked')

if ($selected.length > 0) {
const date = $selected.val()
$("input:radio[name='course-date-2']").val(date).attr('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info provided, I believe what you are looking for is the following as shown in the snippet.
Where you need to set the radio button to checked using `.prop()`.

If this is not it, please provide more details.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
  let selectedValue = $(this).val();
  console.log('radio button changed to: ', selectedValue);
  $('input[type="radio"][value=' + selectedValue + ']').prop('checked', true);
})
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

form + form {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <h2>Form 1</h2>
  <input type="radio" id="course-date-1" name="course-date" value="course1" checked>
  <label for="course-date-1">course 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="course-date-2" name="course-date" value="course2">
  <label for="course-date-2">course 2</label>
</form>

<form>
  <h2>Form 2</h2>
  <input type="radio" id="course-date-1A" name="course-date-A" value="course1" checked>
  <label for="course-date-1A">course 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="course-date-2A" name="course-date-A" value="course2">
  <label for="course-date-2A">course 2</label>
</form>
```